# What is the role of MyBase.New in the following code?

Tags: vb.net

Got this code piece from the following [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/how-to-define-a-class-that-can-provide-identical-functionality). Can someone tell me what is the role of the `MyBase.New()` referred to as `statement 2` below. IMHO it does nothing as there is no base/derived classes - only one class is present. For example, when we pass an integer value to the constructor as in `Dim iList As New simpleList(Of Integer)(2)` the size of the `items` array in `statement 3` is 2 (or 3 elements). Any help pls??

```
Imports System

Module Program
    Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim iList As New simpleList(Of Integer)(2)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module

Public Class simpleList(Of itemType)
    Private items() As itemType
    Private top As Integer
    Private nextp As Integer
    Public Sub New()
        Me.New(9)    'Statement 1
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(ByVal t As Integer)
        MyBase.New()   'Statement 2
        items = New itemType(t) {} 'Statement 3
        top = t
        nextp = 0
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I would agree with you, seems to do nothing.  Have you tried removing it and testing what happens?

Comment: no..but i did do a breakpoint analysis and found that it was not doing anything. But still posted the question for a second opinion to be sure that I am not missing any subtle point

Comment: Well the base is just Object which is an empty constructor so I think safe enough to remove